# Strange behaviour of strpos and &Oslash;

Tags: php, strpos

This seems odd to me but maybe there's a simple explanation.

Why does the following block of code result in `false` despite the needle definitely being part of the haystack?

```
if(strpos("&Oslash;25x&Oslash;2", "&Oslash;")){
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[strpos](http://php.net/strpos) is finding that string at offset 0, which evaluates as false. To truly detect if it's not found, you need to explicitly check both type *and* value using either `===` or `!==` [operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), for example:

```
if (strpos("&Oslash;25x&Oslash;2", "&Oslash;") !== false) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

This is quite well covered in the manual too.

Comment: Spot-on! Nice one, I'll accept your answer as soon as the website will let me. Thanks :)

Comment: Now you've said it, it makes perfect sense. I don't know why I didn't think of it. More coffee needed I think.

Answer (score 0):

`strpos` will return `0` if the needle is at the very start of the haystack. But `0` evaluates to boolean `false`, so your `if` condition fails.

You need to compare to `false`, which is the return value if the needle isn't found at all:

```
if (false !== strpos("&Oslash;25x&Oslash;2", "&Oslash;")) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```